Frame dragging caused by a stream of particles with aligned spins
In theory, does an elementary particle, with intrinsic spin, induce an immeasurably tiny amount of rotational frame-dragging, i.e. can quantum spin cause a Lense-Thirring effect?
There is the Einstein-de Haas effect, where a change in the spins of electrons causes a change in rotation of the object they are part of, due to conservation of angular momentum.
Also, protons apparently do have angular momentum contributing to their spin.
This seems to indicate that quantum spin could also cause relativistic effects like frame-dragging, just like regular rotation.
If so, would then a ludicrous number of particles, with all their spins aligned, combine to eventually induce a measurable amount of frame drag, or would they always cancel each other out?
Would this be possible, in principle, with an enormous stream of aligned electrons, protons, or even a polarized laser beam?
Or would the stream collapse into a black hole before reaching the required density?

see the Kerr-Newman-Dirac electron

Technically, spin and angular momentum are different (“since elementary particles are point-like, self-rotation is not well-defined for them”, quoth Wikipedia). Spin more accurately tells you how the phase of the particle changes over time with physical “rotation”, not how its orientation changes, since its “orientation” as described classically is ill-defined. They are analogous in some ways, but in general relativity, “angular momentum” is, in the stress-energy tensor, represented as momenta in particular locations around an axis of rotation.
This is also how classical mechanics represents angular momentum, but particle spin doesn’t actually measure the same thing in the same relativistic sense. Plus, describing frame-dragging at the quantum level would require an accurate theory of quantum gravity, which we don’t have yet. Maybe there is “spin-dragging” near fermions or vector/tensor bosons or hadrons with nonzero spin, but if there is, its specific formulation would require knowledge of how gravity works quantum-mechanically.

We don't have a working theory of quantum gravity, but perhaps we can say something like, "in a valid theory of quantum gravity, an elementary particle's spin must, or must not, induce frame dragging, like we can say that a graviton must have spin 2? Or if that is not known, what about protons, which apparently do have angular momentum, as part of their spin? ( https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2775 )

We can tell that in some theories spin might correspond to a relativistic-sense angular momentum, that's the easy part; the hard part is trying to figure out how to quantify the gravitational results of that at the quantum scale.
